# Derive a center point and radius from a set of GPS coordinates and bearings

Tags: android, geolocation, spherical-geometry

I have a problem similar to [Triangulation: Estimate a location using lat/long coordinates and bearings](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/216218/triangulation-estimate-a-location-using-lat-long-coordinates-and-bearings).

I have a series of GPS coordinates and bearings for each coordinate as well as accuracy for each bearing (+- 15 in each direction, for example). I used Midpoint calculation to get the center of the points and that's fairly accurate but isn't exact enough for my use case and doesn't give me a true radius of how large the search area can be.

I would like to find an algorithm that will allow me to pass in the GPS coordinates along with the bearings and the accuracy for each bearing and give me the center point of the overlapping bearings as well as a radius of a circle on the center based on the overlap of the bearings +- accuracy. I don't know what this algorithm is called but if given the name and some info I can probably write something to get it into my program and make it work.